# Different precision in C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, double, fortran77

For a project I'm working on I've coded in C++ a very simple function :

`Fne(x) = 0.124*x*x`, the problem is when i compute the value of the function

for `x = 3.8938458092314270` with both Fortran 77 and C++ languages , i got different precison.

For Fortran I got `Fne(x) = 1.8800923323458316` and for C++i got `Fne(x) = 1.8800923630725743`. For both languages, the Fne function is coded for double precision values, and return also double precision values.

C++ code:

```
double FNe(double X) {
    double FNe_out;
    FNe_out = 0.124*pow(X,2.0);
    return FNe_out;
}
```

Fortran code:

```
  real*8 function FNe(X)
  implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
  FNe = 0.124*X*X
  return
  end
```

Can you please help me to find where this difference is from?

Answer (score 7):

One source of difference is the default treatment, by C++ and by Fortran, of literal constants such as your `0.124`.  By default Fortran will regard this as a single-precision floating-point number (on almost any computer and compiler combination that you are likely to use), while C++ will regard it as a double-precision f-p number.

In Fortran you can specify the `kind` of a f-p number (or any other intrinsic numeric constant for that matter and absent any compiler options to change the most-likely default behaviour) by suffixing the *kind-selector* like this

```
0.124_8
```

Try that, see what results.

Oh, and while I'm writing, why are you writing Fortran like it was 1977 ?  And to all the other Fortran experts hereabouts, yes, I know that `*8` and `_8` are not best practice, but I haven't the time at the moment to expand on all that.

Comment: yeah it works, i got the same precision now, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Concerning the way i'm writting the fortran, it's not really my code, my job consist actually on converting a long fortran 77 program into a C++ one

Answer (score 1):

As High Performance Mark pointed out, the default precision of literals is the issue. Using

```
double xx = 3.8938458092314270;
std::cout << std::setprecision(16);
std::cout << " (float) * x*x: " << 0.124f*xx*xx << std::endl;
std::cout << "(double) * x*x: " << 0.124*xx*xx << std::endl;
```

We get

```
 (float) * x*x: 1.880092332345832
(double) * x*x: 1.880092363072574
```

which is the same difference you noticed.