# How to get Real value precision in C++ Same as Fortran (Pararel Studio XE Compiler)

Tags: c++, floating-point, fortran

I have an almost large **Fortran 77** code which I'm trying to write it in **c++**. 
the Fortran code has too many math formulas and i have to get same parameter value in c++.

I have a code like this in Fortran :

```
  implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
  real *8 test
  test=3.14159**2
  print *,test
```

And output is :  **9.86958772810000**

In the c++ code (i use pow for just a sample i have this problem in every math formula):

```
//  1st Try
double test=pow(3.14159,2);
cout <<std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1) <<fixed <<test;
```

And output is : **9.86958885192871**

I know that i can specify the kind of a **f-p number** by suffixing the kind-selector like this (but it's for fortran i need to get same value in c++
0:

```
real test=3.14159_8**2
```

As is described in this question [Different precision in C++ and Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455556/different-precision-in-c-and-fortran)

i also tried this in c++ and the output was :

```
   //  2nd Try as users suggested in the comments
  float test2 = pow(3.14159, 2);
```

the output **9.8695878982543945**

and if i try :

```
   //  3rd Try as users suggested in the comments
  float test2 = pow(3.14159f, 2);
```

output will be : **9.8695888519287109**

which still has differences.

** I need to get same value in c++ not Fortran** because the Fortran project uses this parameter all over the project and i have to get same output.

So is there anyway i get same Float/Double precision in c++?

- For Fortran i use Pararel Studio XE Compiler 2017
- For c++ Visual Studio 2017

Any help would be appreciated.(**thank you all for helping**).

as Kerndog73 Asked i tried

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::digits // value is 53
std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559 //value is 1
```

**P.S: More Detail**

It's one part of my **original** FORTRAN code, as you can see i need to have all 10 precision in c++ to get same values (this code **draws** a shape in a text file at the end of the code, and my c++ code is not similar to that shape because precision values are not the same):

```
  // in the last loop i have a value like this 9292780397998.33
 // all precision have used 

      dp=p2-p1
      dr=(r2-r1)/(real(gx-1))
      dfi=2*3.14159*zr/(real(gy-1))
      test=3.14159**2
      print *,test
      r11=r1
      print *,'dp , dr , dfi'
      print *,dp,dr,dfi
      do 11 i=1,gx
        r(i)=r11
        st(i)=dr*r(i)*dfi
        r11=r11+dr
         print *, r11,r(i),st(i)
 11   continue

      dh=h02-h01
      do 1 i=1,gx
        do 2 j=1,gy
          h0=h01+dh*(r(i)-r1)/(r2-r1)
          hkk=hk(i,j)
          if (hkk.eq.10) then
            hk(i,j)=hkkk
          end if
          h00=h0+hk(i,j)
          h(i,j)=h00/1000000.
          !print *, i,j, h(i,j)
          !print*, h(i,j)
 2      continue
 1    continue
!
!      write(30,501) '     '
 do 12 i=1,gx
        do 22 j=1,gy
          h3=h(i,j)**3
          h3r(i,j)=h3*r(i)
          h3ur(i,j)=h3/r(i)
          !print *,i,j, h3ur(i,j)
          p0(i,j)=p1+dp*(r(i)-r1)/(r2-r1)
           !print *,i,j, p0(i,j)
 22     continue
 12   continue

      drfi=dr/(dfi*48*zmu)
      dfir=dfi/(dr*48*zmu)
      omr=om*dr/8.
       print *,'drfi,dfir,omr,zmu'
      print *,drfi,dfir,omr,zmu
           !p1 = 10000
      !do 100 k=1,giter
        do 32 i=1,gx
          do 42 j=1,gy
            if (i.eq.1) then

              pp(i,j)=p1**2
              goto 242
            end if
            if (i.eq.gx) then
              pp(i,j)=p2**2
              goto 242
            end if
            if (j.eq.1.) then
                temp1=drfi*(2*h3ur(i,1)+h3ur(i,(gy-1))+h3ur(i,2))
              a=drfi*(2*h3ur(i,1)+h3ur(i,(gy-1))+h3ur(i,2))+
     &          dfir*(2*h3r(i,1)+h3r(i-1,1)+h3r(i+1,1))
     &          -omr*r(i)*(h(i,(gy-1))-h(i,2))/p0(i,1)

              b=drfi*(h3ur(i,1)+h3ur(i,(gy-1)))+
     &          omr*r(i)*(h(i,(gy-1))+h(i,1))/p0(i,(gy-1))

              c=drfi*(h3ur(i,1)+h3ur(i,2))-
     &          omr*r(i)*(h(i,1)+h(i,2))/p0(i,2)

              d=dfir*(h3r(i,1)+h3r(i-1,1))

              e=dfir*(h3r(i,1)+h3r(i+1,1))

              pp(i,j)=(b*p0(i,(gy-1))**2+c*p0(i,2)**2+
     &          d*p0(i-1,1)**2+e*p0(i+1,1)**2)/a

              goto 242
              end if

            if (j.eq.gy) then
              a=drfi*(2*h3ur(i,gy)+h3ur(i,(gy-1))+h3ur(i,2))+
     &          dfir*(2*h3r(i,gy)+h3r(i-1,gy)+h3r(i+1,gy))
     &          -omr*r(i)*(h(i,(gy-1))-h(i,2))/p0(i,gy)

              b=drfi*(h3ur(i,gy)+h3ur(i,(gy-1)))+
     &          omr*r(i)*(h(i,(gy-1))+h(i,gy))/p0(i,(gy-1))

              c=drfi*(h3ur(i,gy)+h3ur(i,2))-
     &          omr*r(i)*(h(i,gy)+h(i,2))/p0(i,2)

              d=dfir*(h3r(i,gy)+h3r(i-1,gy))

              e=dfir*(h3r(i,gy)+h3r(i+1,gy))

              pp(i,j)=(b*p0(i,(gy-1))**2+c*p0(i,2)**2+
     &          d*p0(i-1,gy)**2+e*p0(i+1,gy)**2)/a

              goto 242
            end if

            a=drfi*(2*h3ur(i,j)+h3ur(i,j-1)+h3ur(i,j+1))+
     &        dfir*(2*h3r(i,j)+h3r(i-1,j)+h3r(i+1,j))
     &        -omr*r(i)*(h(i,j-1)-h(i,j+1))/p0(i,j)

            b=drfi*(h3ur(i,j)+h3ur(i,j-1))+
     &        omr*r(i)*(h(i,j-1)+h(i,j))/p0(i,j-1)

            c=drfi*(h3ur(i,j)+h3ur(i,j+1))-
     &        omr*r(i)*(h(i,j)+h(i,j+1))/p0(i,j+1)

            d=dfir*(h3r(i,j)+h3r(i-1,j))

            e=dfir*(h3r(i,j)+h3r(i+1,j))

            pp(i,j)=(b*p0(i,j-1)**2+c*p0(i,j+1)**2+
     &        d*p0(i-1,j)**2+e*p0(i+1,j)**2)/a  

 242        continue

            ppp=pp(i,j)
            print *,ppp
            pneu=sqrt(ppp)
            palt=p0(i,j)
            p0(i,j)=palt+(pneu-palt)/2.
            !print *,p0(i,j)
            wt(i,j)=zmu*om*om*((r(i)+dr)**2+r(i)**2)/(2*h(i,j))
             !print *,r(i)
            p00(i,j)=p0(i,j)/100000.
            !print *, p00(i,j)
 42       continue
 32     continue
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203819/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-how-to-get-real-value-precision-in-c-same-a).

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2017 I cannot reproduce your issue, irrespective of the floating point mode. Please list all compiler flags you are using.

Comment: @PeteKirkham have yo tried this on vs 2017?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282) since you keep thinking that it's the assignment that has problem but didn't show any [mcve]. The issue is not in the precision but in the way you print out the values

Comment: @phuclv i added fortran code (the codes will draw a shape in notepad at the end of code), as you can see it uses all 10 precision on all math formula so my code in c++ have differs to those values. and i tried "`float,double,const double`"

Comment: I've read it and it's still about precision. If the Fortran version prints less precision then just round it, in the other case set the precision to a larger value

Comment: unfortunately any change in FORTRAN cause i don't get correct shape which it draws. and in my c++ the shape i draw is totally different because the values are not the same. :)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a program to output all possible results in the 3 formats, with casting done to each type at the various possible times:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// use `volatile` extensively to inhibit "float store" optimizations

template<class T>
void pp(volatile T val)
{
    const size_t prec = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(prec);
    std::cout << std::left;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0');
    std::cout << std::setw(prec+2) << val;
}

int main()
{
    using L = long double;
    using D = double;
    using F = float;

    volatile L lp = 3.14159l;
    volatile D dp = 3.14159;
    volatile F fp = 3.14159f;

    volatile L lpl = lp;
    volatile D dpl = lp;
    volatile F fpl = lp;
    volatile L lpd = dp;
    volatile D dpd = dp;
    volatile F fpd = dp;
    volatile L lpf = fp;
    volatile D dpf = fp;
    volatile F fpf = fp;

    volatile L lpl2 = powl(lpl, 2);
    volatile D dpl2 = pow(dpl, 2);
    volatile F fpl2 = powf(fpl, 2);
    volatile L lpd2 = powl(lpd, 2);
    volatile D dpd2 = pow(dpd, 2);
    volatile F fpd2 = powf(fpd, 2);
    volatile L lpf2 = powl(lpf, 2);
    volatile D dpf2 = pow(dpf, 2);
    volatile F fpf2 = powf(fpf, 2);

    std::cout << "lpl2:  "; pp((L)lpl2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)lpl2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)lpl2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "dpl2:  "; pp((L)dpl2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)dpl2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)dpl2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "fpl2:  "; pp((L)fpl2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)fpl2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)fpl2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "lpd2:  "; pp((L)lpd2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)lpd2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)lpd2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "dpd2:  "; pp((L)dpd2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)dpd2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)dpd2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "fpd2:  "; pp((L)fpd2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)fpd2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)fpd2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "lpf2:  "; pp((L)lpf2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)lpf2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)lpf2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "dpf2:  "; pp((L)dpf2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)dpf2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)dpf2); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "fpf2:  "; pp((L)fpf2); std::cout << "  "; pp((D)fpf2); std::cout << "  "; pp((F)fpf2); std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

On my Linux system, this outputs:

```
       long double           double             float
lpl2:  9.869587728100000000  9.869587728100001  9.869588
dpl2:  9.869587728099999069  9.869587728099999  9.869588
fpl2:  9.869588851928710938  9.869588851928711  9.869589
lpd2:  9.869587728099999262  9.869587728099999  9.869588
dpd2:  9.869587728099999069  9.869587728099999  9.869588
fpd2:  9.869588851928710938  9.869588851928711  9.869589
lpf2:  9.869588472080067731  9.869588472080068  9.869589
dpf2:  9.869588472080067731  9.869588472080068  9.869589
fpf2:  9.869588851928710938  9.869588851928711  9.869589
```

Base on this, it's *possible* that you're showing too few digits but Intel's 80-bit format, which is `long double` on Linux (and, I believe, most x86 OSes), but normally unavailable on Windows.

It's also possible that you're using decimal floats.

But it's also possible your Fortran runtime was just plain broken, many float<->string libraries can generously be described as COMPLETE AND UTTER CRAP.

It's a good habit to use hexadecimal float I/O for reliability.

Comment: in your code first `long double` is same as my fortran output, what do you suggest about getting same values all over code? and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use a multiprecision arithmetic library for C++ that gives you more control over the format of numeric values than float, double, etc. in C++.

For example, using Boost.Multiprecision the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    using number = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<8>>;

    number pi_five_sig_digits{ 3.14159 };
    number value = boost::multiprecision::pow(pi_five_sig_digits, number(2));

    std::cout << "3.14159 ** 2 = " << std::setprecision(15) << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

yields

> 3.14159 ** 2 = 9.8695877281

Comment: there's absolutely no reason to use multiprecision which is magnitudes slower. `real*8` is just IEEE-754 double precision

Answer (score -1):

The way that can work in `cout` **until now** is what @kerndog73 suggested.(thank you so much)
**but my poblem would not solve with `cout`**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int prec = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 - 1;

int main() {
  const double testD = std::pow(3.14159, 2.0);
  const float testF = std::pow(3.14159f, 2.0f);
  std::cout << "Double: " << std::setprecision(prec) << std::fixed << testD << '\n';
  std::cout << "Float:  " << std::setprecision(prec) << std::fixed << testF << '\n';
}
```

and outputs are :

Double

**9.86958772810000** // exactly same as FORTRAN 77 output

Float

**9.86958885192871**

Comment: isn't this exactly what o11c said? You're just not printing enough digits

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` is the precision of double, which is much larger than float, therefore printing a `float` with that precision doesn't make much sense unless you want to know the trash digits after that

Comment: they are not trash digit !

Comment: float can be precise to ~6-7 digits (unless you're using some weird non-existent compiler that maps double to float), everything after that is "trash"

Comment: I'm not using float

Comment: you're using `const float testF = std::pow(3.14159f, 2.0f);` in the above code

Comment: its what another user suggested you can see comments in discussion. it was what he suggest. he send this in a fiddle